# Atom Editor Syntax Grammar: How to match function call?

Tags: sublimetext3, textmate, sublime-text-plugin, atom-editor, textmatebundles

I'm writing a grammar file for the [Atom Editor](https://atom.io) for a specific (yet unsupported language).

While I'm getting expected results up to now, I'm not sure how to accomplish the following.

I want functions declared in the current file that are called in the same file to be highlighted. For now, the function calls don't get matched/highlighted.

I know it is possible as C files are properly highlighted. For example, in the following screenshot, the call to function `my_function()` gets highlighted in blue:

[image: helloworld.c]

Right now, function definitions are matched with the following cson snippet:

```
{
    'comment':  'Functions'
    'match':    '^\\s*(function)\\s*(\\w*)'
    'captures':
        '1':
            'name':     'variable.other.newlang'
        '2':
            'name':     'support.function.any-method.newlang'
}
```

which is quite basic but work fine. But unfortunately the function calls will not be highlighted the same way as in C.

How can I achieve this?

Note that Atom uses the (almost) same grammar file syntax as Sublime Text 3 and TextMate.

Thanks!

Comment: From what I understand as to now, this is not possible. Atom's C grammar is able to highlights the function call because it can recognize _a_ function call, not _the_ function call. So in the above example line 3 and line 11 are not related; it's two different matching rules in the grammar.

I'm saying it's not possible because in the new language I'm working with, there is not way to reliably recognize a function call; it is not using the parenthesis as in C (or any other characters).

Comment: Well your language has to have _some_ sort of defined syntax of how a function call has to look like.

Comment: This was the issue back then; that language did not have delimiters for the function calls! You could for example chain multiple commands like this `result = commandOne commandTwo commandThree argument` where the output of one `command*` is the input of the other...